# UniSwapV2 Testnet Support

Tags: solidity, defi, sepolia, uniswapv2

As you may be aware, the Goerli Testnet has been deprecated, and furthermore, UniSwapV2 is not supported on the Sepolia Testnet. What would be the recommended solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this git: https://github.com/islishude/uniswapv2-solc0.8/blob/main/src/test/UniswapV2Router.spec.ts

Take a look at directory `src/test`, so you can deploy yourself and test it on your local node

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna deploy yourself, then there are certain Uni V2 routers deployed on sepolia by other devs, like [0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008#code) you can use them as well.

I have also created a github issue for this same thing - https://github.com/Uniswap/interface/issues/7642

Comment: really i created a token by using 0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008 address but when i want to add LP and do swap in the uniswap v2 sit at address app.uniswap.org/pools/v2 and app.uniswap.org/swap , i can create the LP but when i go to do swap , not recognized and it seems the LP not created , is there any solution or any token contract source code that have been tested on sepolia testnet to use it as starting point ? thanks in advance. –

Comment: Well, if you are using this address, that means you are deploying on sepolia, and then you are trying to use the uniswap dapp which doesn't support sepolia. While working on sepolia you can't use the official uniswap dapp